# How Do I allow a user search for contents in a file in C?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, search

I have a text file with different details of contacts.
It's basically like this

> John Doe 024587 24th July Works From Home Lives at Home Jane Doe
>   024584 25th August Works from Work Lives at Work

I want to be able to search for "John Doe" or "Jane Doe" in the file.

I've decided to read contents from the file and store them in an array. I want to know how to search through the array. This code doesn't seem to cut it. 
noOfContacts is the number of contacts in the file.

```
          readFile.open("book.txt", ios::out);
          while (!readFile.eof())
          {
            cout << "Enter anything you wish to search" <<endl;
            getline(cin, searchString);

            for (int k = 0; k < noOfContacts; k++)
            {       
                        getline (readFile,name[k]);
                                readFile >> phone[k];
                getline(readFile,birth[k]);
                getline(readFile,address[k]);
                getline(readFile,workplace[k]);


                cout << name[k]<<endl;
                cout << phone[k]<< endl;
                cout << birth[k]<<endl;
                cout << address[k]<<endl;
                cout << workplace[k]<<endl;


                break;
            }
```

Comment: Uhm, yeah, I don't see any compare with what was entered...

Comment: I've tried another method that works. I'll post it here in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a for loop? Would it not be easier to do something like:

```
 unsigned found = 0;

 cout << "Enter anything you wish to search" <<endl;
        getline(cin, searchString);

 while(!readFile.eof() && (found==0)){  
     getline(readFile,testString);

     found=testString.find(searchString);
 }

 if (found == 0) {
 cout << "String found!\n " << testString.c_str(); << endl;
 }
 else{
 cout << "String Not Found!\n";
 }
```

I've not tested this code but hopefully it'll give you an idea of which way to go.

Comment: So this is the new code. It works if I define the string variable searchTerm. But the getline function isn't working so my user can enter a search term.

Comment: Here's the link to it https://github.com/olabinjo/C---contacts-project/blob/master/The%20search.md